# Installing gitkraken on fedora 26

Tags: installation, gitkraken, dnf, fedora-26

I'm trying to install gitkraken on my Fedora 26 since few hours I installed it from but the dependecies looks to don't be resolved

```
Node started time: 1507496118430
libcurl-gnutls.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: libcurl-gnutls.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:173:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:187:18)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

And I already have installed `libcurl` and `gnutls` packages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create symbol link

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 /opt/gitkraken/libcurl-gnutls.so.4`

Comment: On openSUSE:

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libcurl.so /usr/lib64/libcurl-gnutls.so.4`

Comment: - or -
sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/libcurl.so.4 /usr/lib64/libcurl-gnutls.so.4

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I don't know whose package is required but I do this command:

```
dnf install curl*
```

and next install this package:
ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/updates/testing/26/x86_64/l/libcurl-7.53.1-11.fc26.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it following these commands: https://gist.github.com/aelkz/17528d2f6a5db73185c7dfbd28e49d18

Hope they work for you as well